# Better way of reading and accumulating data from sql

Tags: c#, sql, datareader

I'm working through some possibilities of reading data with C# from sql, and I'm sure better ways exist.

What I have is a (fairly complex) sql select statement that returns 3 columns.  Eg. Personnel ID,  TaskID and HoursWorked

What I want to do, is populate another table with 2 columns and the data should like something like:

```
COL1     |   COL2
---------------------
"John"   |   "Tsk01 (2 Hours), Tsk02 (7 Hours), Tsk03 (4 Hours)" 
"Peter"  |   "Tsk01 (4 Hours), Tsk03 (2 Hours), Tsk04 (3 Hours)"
```

So, the one obvious way is to put my sql statement in a data reader (sorted by person), iterate through that and then write the data to my second table every time I get a new person.  But that just feels cumbersome.  There must be an easier way?

Comment: Why do you want one field containing a comma delimited list of values?  That's an SQL anti-pattern.  The *(normalised)* structure that you're starting with is best-practice.

Comment: Acceptable question...  The second table is actually acting as an Audit Trace.  All that it 'important' is the first column.  The second column will just be additional Notes.  Even if the data gets truncated it is not an issue.

Comment: Even your audit table should be normalised.  Assuming `'John'` and `'Peter'`actually have id's in another table, you're only going to have a table of 3 columns of integers, 4 bytes per column, 12 bytes in total per row *(each person/task combination)*.  Your strings, however, are taking up many more bytes than that; `', Tsk02 (7 Hours)'` is a lot more than 12 bytes.

Comment: True.  But the table design has been done a while ago and cannot really be changed at this time.  I'll have to work with what I have.

Comment: Which RDBMS?  SQL Server?  MySQL?  Oracle?  etc?

Comment: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

Answer (score 3):

It is cumbersome and very inefficient.

There are some considerations here that you should make:

- Do not violate the [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First%5fnormal%5fform#Atomicity) of your database fields. One piece of information per field.
- Let the database engine do all the work before you fetch the data into your code